# calculating power in a recursive way coffeescript case of exponent == 0

Tags: algorithm, function, recursion, coffeescript

I am trying to write fun calculating in a recursive way powers for given base  and exponent (only postive integers with 0 are assumed to be correct input)

Code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/andilab/hcqBe/

It does not work for the case of `0`.

```
 pow = (a,p) ->
        if p >= 1
            if p == 1
                a
            else
                p = p-1
                a*pow(a,p)
        else
            1
```

Have I done something wrong?

Comment: have a look on http://jsfiddle.net/andilab/hcqBe/ `base` is `a` and the `exponent` is `p`

Comment: The function seems to work. The output is 1, as expected. However there's something else wrong with that fiddle, because it doesn't add the result to the DOM

Comment: @NiklasB. how did you test it?

Comment: @andi I just replaced the `append`s with `console.log`. And then I looked at the console. Also with your original code it says "undefined is not a function" or something like that, so it produces an error that causes it to stop

Comment: @NiklasB. Look it works when replaced console.log http://i.imgur.com/KhbXtGO.png

Comment: @andi Yes, if you wonder why your original fiddle did not work, you should ask a different question, because the function is alright